# How can I get aggregate dollar values out of Zillow?

Tags: data-request, economics, real-estate

I am interested in getting aggregate dollar values for listings/sales on Zillow (for the whole country summed together, for example). Unfortunately, [Zillow's data page](http://www.zillow.com/research/data/) seems to only show the "ZHVI", an index value, not a total dollar value. Is there any way to get the total dollar value?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the zillow terms of use to make sure your use is appropriate:

http://www.zillow.com/wikipages/Privacy-and-Terms-of-Use/

This is not an open data set at this time.  However the API may satisfy your needs:

http://www.zillow.com/howto/api/APIOverview.htm

Comment: I don't see how this helps. I see no API call for requesting aggregate data.

Comment: I just said the API *may* satisfy your needs.  I don't know.  API calls would help if you really wanted the value.  You would have to make many API calls and aggregate them yourself if that was the route you wanted to take.  Are you looking for zillow specific data, or real estate (MLS) data in general?  This is a post describing a similar problem and may be helpful: http://geekestateblog.com/real-estate-tech-question-getting-nationwide-mls-listing-data/

Comment: If even thought of trying to query every house in Zillow, the company would put out a contract on me.